# Получить значение enum элемента по его ключу в строке Swift

Tags: строки, swift, enum

В общем есть большой enum (более 1000 элементов), в котором нужно получить значение по ключу. Причем значение это строка.

```
public struct Awesome {
   public enum Solid: String, Amazing {
        case ad = "\u{f641}"
        case addressBook = "\u{f2b9}"
        case addressCard = "\u{f2bb}"
        case adjust = "\u{f042}"
        case airFreshener = "\u{f5d0}"
        ...
   }
}
```

По умолчанию вызов иконки происходит следующим образом

```
Awesome.Solid.ad.image
```

Однако мне нужно производить передавать в вызов строку с названием иконки, что то типа такого:

```
let iconName = "ad"
Awesome.Solid.iconName.image
```

тут я закономерно получаю ошибку, что не существует такого элемента

есть ли способ обратиться таким образом к enum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так, например:

```
enum Solid: String, CaseIterable {
    case ad = "\u{f641}"
    case addressBook = "\u{f2b9}"
    case addressCard = "\u{f2bb}"
    case adjust = "\u{f042}"
    case airFreshener = "\u{f5d0}"
}

for name in Solid.allCases where name == Solid.ad {
            print("\(name.rawValue) is a icon.")
}
```

Или вот так:

```
print("\(Solid.ad.rawValue) is a icon.")
```

Comment: В целом похоже на правду, но тут такой момент, что возвращается строка, а не тип Awesome.Solid, и из строки в рамках либы отрисовать иконку на вьюхе нет возможности

Comment: let iconImage = UIImage(named: Solid.ad.rawValue)